# Using stack class to checks whether brackets ( "(", ")", "<", ">" ) are balanced - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I have this code to check whether or not brackets are balanced within a piece of text in a string.

```
def balanced_brackets(text):

    s = Stack()

    for character in text:
        if character == "(":
            s.push(character)
        elif character == ")":
            if s.is_empty():
                return False
            else:  
                s.pop()
        if character == "<":
            s.push(character)
        elif character == ">":
            if s.is_empty():
                return False
            else:
                s.pop()

    if s.is_empty():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For the following tests:

```
print(balanced_brackets('(<x)>(())()'))
print(balanced_brackets('x<y)(>z'))
print(balanced_brackets('<(x)<y>)z'))
```

The following outputs should all print

```
False
```

but they print

```
True
```

for some reason. I need help on determining why this is. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't checked whether your closer actually *matches* the opener you pop.

Comment: How do i check if the opener is in the stack.

Comment: I tried going 
elif "(" in s
and
elif "<" in s
but that gives me a error saying that the stack is not iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it this way using a dictionary to map which closing bracket belongs to which opening bracket. This way you can simplify the code to only one `if/elif` block, instead of one for each bracket type. You can easily add more brackets to the dictionary as well.

```
# Map Closing to Opening
BRACKETS = {
    ')' : '(',
    '>' : '<'
}

def balanced_brackets(text):
    s = Stack()
    for c in text:
        # if opening bracket
        if c in BRACKETS.values():
            s.push(c)
        # if closing bracket
        elif c in BRACKETS:
            if s.is_empty():
                return False
            # if opening bracket doesn't match closing bracket popped from Stack
            elif BRACKETS[c] != s.pop():
                return False

    return s.is_empty()

# Output
>>> balanced_brackets('(<x)>(())()')
False
>>> balanced_brackets('x<y)(>z')
False
>>> balanced_brackets('<(x)<y>)z')
False
>>> balanced_brackets('<((<<hello>>))>')
True
>>> balanced_brackets('<')
False
```